# Use Schema in Trigger

Tags: bulkification, schema

In attempting to "Bulkify" my trigger, it was suggested that I use Schema for getting RecordTypeId. As I'm not really a developer (I'm just taking a stab at updating the code that was created by a developer no longer with our company), can anyone help me out with this?

Thanks!

[Is my Trigger properly "Bulkified"?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/266362/is-my-trigger-properly-bulkified/266381#266381)

```
trigger ContactGetTerritoryReference on Contact (before insert, before update) {
    Map<String,Territory_Reference__c> Terr2Terr_SA = new Map<String,Territory_Reference__c>();
    Map<String,Territory_Reference__c> Terr2Terr_DTT = new Map<String,Territory_Reference__c>();
    Map<String,Territory_Reference__c> Terr2Terr_OC = new Map<String,Territory_Reference__c>();
    //Map<String,Contact> Contact_RecordTypeID = new Map<String,Contact>(); 

    Set<String> SA = new Set<String>();   
    for(Contact a:Trigger.new){
        //filtering out dealer contact record type
        if (a.RecordTypeID !='012440000002T6J' && a.Account_Record_Type__c == 'Agency Establishment'){
            //something new
            SA.add(a.Agency__c);
            //a.Agency_Name__c = a.Agency__c; // the default agency name will be the SA
        }
        else if (a.Account_Record_Type__c != 'Agency Establishment' ){
            a.VOSS_Manager__c = null;
            a.NAIS_VSEN_Mgr__c = null;
            a.CBM__c = null;
            a.PSE__c = null; 
            a.RVP__c = null;
            a.MTSS__c = null; 
            a.Inside_Sales_Representative__c = null;
            a.VPSE__c = null;
        }
    }

    for (Territory_Reference__c t : [SELECT MTSS__c, AGENCY_DTT__c, NAIS_VOSS_Mgr__c, VSEN__c, NAIS_VSEN_Mgr__c, AGENT_DTT__c, AGENCY__c, AGENCY_ID__c, SA_DTT_KEY__c, VOSS__c, PSE__c, PSM__c, MSO__c, RVP__c, Area_Title__c, REGION__c, RMOS__c, ASD__c, CBM__c, VPSE__c, VSPM__c FROM Territory_Reference__c WHERE AGENCY_ID__c IN : SA]){
        Terr2Terr_SA.put(t.AGENCY_ID__c,t);
        Terr2Terr_DTT.put(t.AGENT_DTT__c,t);
        Terr2Terr_OC.put(t.AGENCY_DTT__c,t);      
    }

    if (!Terr2Terr_SA.isEmpty()){
        for(Contact a:Trigger.new){
            if (Terr2Terr_DTT.get(a.Dtt__c) <> null && a.RecordTypeID !='012440000002T6J' && a.Account_Record_Type__c == 'Agency Establishment' && a.Establishment_Type__c != 'Open Coverage'){
                Territory_Reference__c  t2t = Terr2Terr_DTT.get(a.Dtt__c);
                //a.Agency_Name__c = t2t.AGENCY__c;
                a.Inside_Sales_Representative__c = t2t.VSEN__c;
                a.VPSE__c = t2t.VPSE__c;
            }

            if (Terr2Terr_OC.get(a.Dtt__c) <> null && a.RecordTypeID !='012440000002T6J' && a.Account_Record_Type__c == 'Agency Establishment' && a.Establishment_Type__c == 'Open Coverage'){
                Territory_Reference__c  t2t = Terr2Terr_OC.get(a.Dtt__c);
                //a.Agency_Name__c = t2t.AGENCY__c;
                a.Inside_Sales_Representative__c = t2t.VSEN__c;
                a.VPSE__c = t2t.VPSE__c;
            }


            if (Terr2Terr_SA.get(a.Agency__c)<>null && a.RecordTypeID !='012440000002T6J' && a.Account_Record_Type__c == 'Agency Establishment'){
                Territory_Reference__c  t2t = Terr2Terr_SA.get(a.Agency__c);
                //a.Agency_Name__c = t2t.AGENCY__c;  


                a.VOSS_Manager__c = t2t.NAIS_VOSS_Mgr__c;
                a.NAIS_VSEN_Mgr__c = t2t.NAIS_VSEN_Mgr__c;
                a.CBM__c = t2t.MSO__c;
                a.PSE__c = t2t.PSE__c;
                //a.PSM__c = t2t.PSM__c;
                //a.RVP__c = t2t.RMOS__c;
                //a.VOSS__c = t2t.VOSS__c;
                a.RVP__c = t2t.RVP__c;
                a.MTSS__c = t2t.MTSS__c;
                a.Establishment_SA_Number__c = a.AGENCY__c;
                a.Establishment_Dtt__c = a.DTT__c;
                a.Establishment_Record_Type__c = a.Account_Record_Type__c;
                a.Establishment_Type2__c = a.Establishment_Type__c;
                //a.Xerox_Entity__c = t2t.REGION__c;
                //a.Area_Title_t2t__c = t2t.Area_Title__c;      
                //a.ASD__c = t2t.ASD__c;
                //a.CBM__c = t2t.CBM__c;
                //a.VSPM__c = t2t.VSPM__c;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ytiq has a suggestion for you on their answer to the previous question (at the end).

Answer (score 0):

When "bulkifying" things, the other question correctly pointed you in the right direction - you want all of your database operations outside of loops, and dealing with Lists or Maps, as you are.  The Schema reference I believe is so that you can be rid of hardcoding Ids.  The [documentation is here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_RecordTypeInfo.htm).

`Schema.SObjectType.<Object Name>.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('<Record Type Name>').getRecordTypeId()` will get you the Id of the RecordType dynamically, rather than relying on it always being the hardcoded value.  So if I have a `Contact` object, and want the `Dealer` RecordTyped contacts, it would be `Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Dealer').getRecordTypeId()` in place of all your hardcoded IDs.  Better yet, store that as a String and use it repeatedly, e.g.:

```
String dealerRecordType = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Dealer').getRecordTypeId();
if(a.RecordTypeId != dealerRecordType) {
// do stuff with non-dealers here
}
```